# Various environments and weird less behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris, less

I am playing with I/O redirection and have problem with less behaving differently in two environments. Both environments are Solaris-based and 
are of the same version.

I am executing program in two environments like this:

env 1:

```
script </dev/pts/1 >&/dev/pts/1 (/dev/pts/1 is my SSH session terminal)
```

env 2:

```
script </dev/console >&/dev/console (/dev/console is Solaris main console)
```

Script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 4>>/tmp/script.log
export PS4='[\D{%FT%TZ}] $(tty): ${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}:    ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'
export BASH_XTRACEFD=4
set -o xtrace

export TERM=xterm-color

file=/path/to/big/file
less -MQEX ${file}
read
```

In env 1 everything works correctly, I am able to control less and scroll up/down, quit etc. In env 2, the less only displays first part of file and quits without being able to scroll up/down or manipulate within the file. env 2 is a script, which is run from SMF manifest. The things I have tried:

1. playing around with various bash options (interactive vs non-interactive), but it doesn't have any influence on this. In both environments I have the following bash options ($-) set "hxB".
2. setting different TERM types didn't affect less behaviour. I have tried "xterm", "vt100" and "vt220".

I am not sure what else should I try or where to look. How should I proceed with the debugging of less behavior? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `$TERM` in the console? It might not be capable to do what you want.

Comment: xterm-color. It works in env 1, but not in env 2.

Answer (score 0):

If that is really a *Solaris* console, it is not compatible with [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) (or *anything* related to a VT100).  VT100s use an escape sequence for scrolling which does interesting things with the Sun hardware.

Referring to the manual page for [wscons](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19109-01/tsolaris8/816-1060/6m7glrk90/index.html), anything that is marked with "SUN" in the name in parenthesis is pretty much guaranteed to be a point of incompatibility.  Like the VT100 scrolling controls, these are escape sequences not part of "ANSI X3.64" (*long ago* withdrawn, replaced by [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)).  The source of your problem is this one:

> `ESC[#r`
>   Set Scrolling (SUNSCRL)
>
> Takes one parameter, *n* (default 0). Sets to *n* an internal register which determines how many lines the screen scrolls up when a line-feed function is performed with the cursor on the bottom line. A parameter of 2 or 3 introduces a small amount of jump when a scroll occurs. A parameter of 34 clears the screen rather than scrolling. The initial setting is 1 on reset.
>
> A parameter of zero initiates wrap mode instead of scrolling. If a linefeed occurs on the bottom line during wrap mode, the cursor goes to the same character position in the top line of the screen. When a line feed occurs, the line that the cursor moves to is cleared and no scrolling occurs. `ESC [ 1 r` exits back to scroll mode.
>
> For more information, see the description of the Line-feed (CTRL-J) control function above.

A VT100-style CSR (change scrolling region) takes two parameters, which are the starting and ending rows of the scrolling region.

Comment: Setting sun-color didn't help. What should be done?

Comment: I read this answer as saying "you can't do it"

Comment: No... I think that if the problem is as I guessed, then OP could have applied the `TERM` setting in the wrong place (or did not reset the terminal modes on the console, leaving it in whatever half-done scrolling was started before) - something to check over. `less` should be able to cope with terminals lacking scrolling regions.

Comment: Removing the line, which sets the terminal to xterm-color and trying again makes some changes. The terminal is started in dumb mode and less at least spits out "Termina not fully functional". I also tried to reset terminal with "reset" and "stty sane; tput rs1", but no avail. I also found out that I am not able to set terminal size as in env 1 (stty cols or stty rows does nothing).

Comment: In a quick check on Solaris 10, it seems that setting TERM to "sun" rather than "sun-color" works better.  I tested with [ded](http://invisible-island.net/ded/ded.html), and see problems with "sun-color".